# print(foo, end="") not working in terminal

Tags: python, printing

So this is some code that is supposed to print text, similar to how Pokemon does. Purely for fun.

The problem is that `print(x, end="")` does not work when the program is run in the terminal, but it works fine when run using IDLE.

```
import time

lorem = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit."

for x in lorem:
    print(x, end="")
    time.sleep(0.03)
```

For some reason the program works fine if I put a print statement before `print(x, end="")`.

```
for x in lorem:
    print()
    print(x, end="")
    time.sleep(0.03)
```

Does anyone have any idea what is causing this? And maybe how to fix it?

Comment: It looks like your terminal doesn't flush the input until you print a newline (which is what the print() in the second program does).  Let the top program run for a while and you should eventually get an output.

Comment: What happens when it doesn't work?

Comment: Add `sys.stdout.flush()` after `print(x, end="")`

Comment: You can run Python unbuffered. Search for the command line setting.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This is happening because python uses a buffer to write to stdout. in order to get the desired effect, you must put `sys.stdout.flush()` at the end of your code...

```
import time, sys

lorem = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit."

for x in lorem:
    print(x, end="")
    time.sleep(0.03)
    sys.stdout.flush()
```

This will print out each character individually at the rate of 1 character per 0.03 seconds

Comment: Alternatively, `print(x, end="", flush=True)`. (python 3.3+ only)